# After Login redirection

Tags: magento-1.9

I used this for after login

```
System > Config > Customer > Costumer Redirect Customer to Account Dashboard after Logging in > NO
```

But after that it redirects to this

```
https://domain.com/customer/account/loginPost/referer/aHR0cHM6Ly9maXRmdXJuLmNvbS8,/
```

How to i fix this?

Comment: If you set `No` then it will redirect you to old page after logging in.What you want to do with that ?

Comment: after setting it redirect to blank page not redirect to old page in above url only shown